# Updating Oracle Table from SQL SERVER

Tags: oracle, updates, sql-server-2016, openquery

I am trying to update an oracle table from sql server using linked server openquery method

```
 UPDATE   target
SET "FIRST_NAME"  =source.FIRST_NAME    ,
    "LAST_NAME"  =source.LAST_NAME  
FROM  (
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([RemoteServer],'SELECT * FROM table1'))  target
INNER JOIN    
table2 source
ON 
    target.PK = source.PK
```

I am getting follwoing error:
Cannot update row as the data in the database has changed.

I am able to fetch data using select statement.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([RemoteServer],'SELECT * FROM table1')  target
INNER JOIN    table2 source
ON 
    target.PK = source.PK
```

WHEN I specify any value of PK then update works.
For e.g

```
UPDATE   target
    SET
    "FIRST_NAME"  =source.FIRST_NAME    ,
    "LAST_NAME"  =source.LAST_NAME  
FROM  (
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([RemoteServer],'SELECT * FROM table1 where PK=1'))  target
INNER JOIN    
table2 source
ON 
    target.PK = source.PK
```

The above query works and 1 row is updated.
But my requirement is to update all row sets from table2(SQL SERVER) to table1(Remote Oracle Table).

I have noticed insert works.

Comment: Can you please fix your formatting and also specify whsch setvervisvwhat I am quite confused as o thought the SQL server table is the soutce

Comment: I have corrected the formatting. Can you please suggest any solution to it.

Comment: Cross platform DML through linked servers is always a nightmare. How many rows are you trying to update? You might have to do this with a cursor. That is, on the SQL Server side you step through individual rows and update the target. This would be OK for thousands of rows but not OK for 100's of thousands of rows

Comment: Thank you.We are trying to update 1000s of records and I have already tried cursor and it's working.But I was wondering what could be the reason for this update not working. And if there is any setup issue that is needed.